# sendKeys() method on Selenium WebDriver while using PhantomJS Driver not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Earlier in the year I created WebDriver test framework for my team QA it runs through multiple forms filling out different flows of the form using either `FirefoxDriver or PhantomJSDriver`. It was working well until recently when running in PhantomJS it now can't run and through this error:

> RouterReqHand - _handle.error - {"line":264,"sourceURL":"phantomjs://code/webelement_request_handler.js","stack":"_postValueCommand@phantomjs://code/webelement_request_handler.js:264:52\n_handle@phantomjs://code/webelement_request_handler.js:72:30\n_reroute@phantomjs://code/request_handler.js:61:20\n_handle@phantomjs://code/session_request_handler.js:120:42\n_reroute@phantomjs://code/request_handler.js:61:20\n_handle@phantomjs://code/router_request_handler.js:78:46"}
>
> phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: TypeError - undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()')
>   Command duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>   System info: host: 'Andrew's-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '172.16.0.82', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=false, databaseEnabled=false, version=2.1.1, platform=OS X 10.11, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={proxyType=direct}, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, driverVersion=1.2.0, locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, browserName=phantomjs, takesScreenshot=true, driverName=ghostdriver, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: c5370630-41c1-11e6-810d-b97a0e25b39f

Looking at the stack trace I have seen this is being caused when the sendKeys() method is called, as I mentioned it had been working fine with no changes for months in PhantomJS, however now it only works in Firefox. Any help would be greatly apreciated.

My maven dependencies (if it helps) are

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: have you upgraded anything like browser, jar etc.

Comment: I hadn't when it stopped working but I did try upgrading PhantomJS to the latest version